# Using DLL registration in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dllregistration

I want to count the no of processes, as each process uses LoadLibary.
I'm thinking of a registering procedure as one option around this.

The idea is when one process uses the library the library can create a separate process
and when the last process logs off the process is closed if its nessary to close it.

has any one done this with a *DLL and how did they implement it? please

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. *What* processes do you want to count? The number of processes currently using your DLL? To what end, I wonder.

Comment: please explain in more details what your underlying problem is

Comment: I still have no idea what your question is. Which processes do you want to count? Why are you counting processes?

Answer (score 2):

DLLs are created to work in memory and in process of executable.

If you are shure you need separate process read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682594(v=vs.85).aspx

http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip1003_2.htm

Important: http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/aa103003a.htm

Comment: There is less promiscuous `SysInit.DllProcEx`, unsure about its RTL version requirements, tho. Also: there was official Borland boilerplate for libraries which need DllMain functionality.

Answer (score 1):

`LoadLibrary()` API call already share the library among all the processes which use it.

Otherwise, any Windows program, which calls a lot of standard librarys (kernel32.dll gdi32.dll....) will use a lot more of memory than needed.

If fact, any `LoadLibrary()` API call will make access of the `.dll` file exports (i.e. the library functions) from the current process. It will "load" the library in the PS memory only once (the first time it's used), then it will **link** the library to the process, i.e. it will set all needed functions from their name.

For instance, if you write in our program:

```
  FHandle := LoadLibrary('library.dll') ;
  FInitialize := GetProcAddress(FHandle, 'Initialize') ;
```

The library won't be loaded from disk to RAM each time. Only the first time it is loaded.

Windows will only search for the exported function named 'Initialize' in the library, then will map its existing copy in the current process address space, then set a pointer to properly call the external Initialize function when needed.

So I really don't get the point of your question: you don't need to "count" library use instance, because **Windows is already doing it for you, better than you should ever implement it**. When no process use a particular library, it just unmap it from memory (OK, I admit this is not exactly what happen, it's much more complicated, but the result is the same).

Linking under Windows is fast and efficient: the .exe format is for instance faster to link that the elf format used for linux, e.g.

In all cases, since the library needs to be linked to the process, you have no choice but to call LoadLibrary, since this is the only way of the library to be available in the process memory space. You could think of a remote execution using pipes or such... but the library model is more efficient in the Windows world.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth explaining a bit about the base address and the impact that not setting it might have on relocation

Comment: @David You're right, but I guess that the question is much more high-level than that. I tried to explain the process loadding mechanism in any OS, since the `LoadLibrary` mechanism seems not to be clear, as far as the question was written. `LoadLibrary` is your friend, not your enemy. :)